# Laravel / Eloquent -- Lookup Table Issue

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have 3 tables that I am trying to work through and am having a hard time connecting them via Eloquent joins.

**Character Table**

```
profileID (PK)
```

**Character Gear Table**

```
profileId (PK) 
qualityId (FK)
```

**Quality Lookup Table**

```
id (PK)
name
```

I am able to access the Character Gear Lookup with the following in my Character Model:

```
public function gear()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\CharacterGear', 'profileId')->where('gearSet', '=', '0');
}
```

How do I get the lookup to work so that I can get the quality name from the Quality Lookup table to tie in to the `gear()` shown above?

Please let me know if you need any further information!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  Eloquent has Nested Relationships and I didn't know that.